Find the average number of children at the root of a Cayley tree.
I am just starting with analytic combinatorics and I came across this problem:

Find the average number of children at the root of a Cayley tree.

The solution goes as:
Specification:
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T_0} = \mathcal{Z} \star\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{\bullet T})\\ \mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \star\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
so the generation functions satisfy
$$T(z, u) = z \exp (uT(z))\\T(z)=z\exp (T(z))$$
For Cayley trees isn't the usual combinatorial class equation
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})?$$
Why do we have two symbol equations here and two generation functions as well and what's the idea?
Thanks!

This is page 179 of the Flajolet and Sedgewick book and OEIS A206855 and looks to be a duplicate of MSE 4712612.

Okay, I think we got it.
